# C# How to catch alphabetical characters

Tags: c#, try-catch

I'm currently working on a height conversion calculator, converting feet and inches to centimetres and want to create a "catch" that will produce an error message when the user inputs alphabetical characters rather than numerical characters, even potentially a catch that will address is the user input is invalid (e.g. entering 5' 111' rather than 5' 11').

The current catch doesn't work:

```
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Convert your height into Centimeters!");
    Console.WriteLine("Please give your height in the form of Feet and Inches, for example: 5'10\"");
    //user enters 5'10"
    heightString = Console.ReadLine();
    //heightString = "5'10""
    heightString = heightString.Remove(heightString.Length - 1);
    //heightString = "5'10"
    posOfInch = heightString.IndexOf("'");
    //posOfInch = 1

            try
            {
            }

            catch ()
            {
                throw new ("Generic Error Message");                    
            }
```

// this catch is invalid within the application

```
    feet = Convert.ToInt16(heightString.Remove(posOfInch));
    //feet = 5
    inches = Convert.ToInt16(heightString.Substring(posOfInch + 1));
    //inches = 10

    inches = (feet * 12) + inches;
    centimetres = (inches * 2.54);

    Console.WriteLine("Your height is " + centimetres + "cm");
    //Console.WriteLine("Please give your height measurement in inches : ");
    //calculating = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    //inches(calculating);
    Console.ReadKey();
    return true;
```

Any advice on how I can challenge this catch issue?

Comment: There is no cast so why you handle the `InvalidCastException`?

Comment: There's no code in the try block to cause an exception - are you asking what you need to put in there to validate your string?

Comment: Apologies, yes. 

I am asking for clarification of what I could place within the codeBlock in order to ensure an error message is displayed if an alphabetical input is provided, rather than a numerical feet and inch value?

Comment: There are two ways to do what you want to do : Using regular expressions or creating a parser (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). Research those a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to catch any exceptions, use `TryParse`:

```
string heightString = "5'10";

short feet, inches;
bool validFormat = false;
int index = heightString.IndexOf("'", StringComparison.Ordinal);

if (index >= 0)
    validFormat = short.TryParse(heightString.Remove(index), out feet)
               && short.TryParse(heightString.Substring(index + 1), out inches);
```

By the way, since you don't cast anywhere, catching an `InvalidCastException` is pointless.

Comment: Sorry, but the example input - `"5'10\""` (please, notice the trailing `"` - inches) fails to be a valid format

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: well, is that valid input? OP has mentioned that this is invalid and that is also the result with above code.-

Comment: @Tim Schmelter: it seems to be since the code in the question `Console.WriteLine("Please give your height in the form of Feet and Inches, for example: 5'10\"");` provides this as an example

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: nice catch, i must admit i'm not famliar with the format of feets and inches. So maybe it's sufficient to simply trim that first: `heightString=heightString.Trim('"');`

Answer (score 0):

Because you also need to do input validation (not just the conversion) I recommend using a regular expression. For instance:

```
\d+'\d{2}'
```

will only accept inputs with 1 or more digit, followed by a quote, in turn followed by other 2 digits and a final quote (just an example, you may find a more selective one).

Moreover if you want to extract the values to the convert them and store them as integers, you can use grouping and extract the values, just by putting parentheses around the input you want to capture.

For reference check this out: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/93804/using-regular-expressions-in-c-net